# javascript code with ember js (password confirm password matching fields with emberjs )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ember.js

i want to write a code of javascript with ember control to control the password and confirm password fields matching with the help of javascript . 
if it is possible with emberjs please let me know i tried this one but its not working with me code.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/8MRcS/12/
```

I don't know when i put this code in my contorl than its not working perfectly in the signup control if i put this in app.js controller than its wokring but i need this inside the signup code.

here is my template code .

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="signup">

        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        {{outlet}}

    <form {{action "submit" on="submit" }}>
        <!-- //This connects to the controller, using the user object -->


        <p><label>Name: {{input type="text" value=user.name required="true"}}</label></p>
        <p><label>Username: {{input type="text" value=user.username required="true"}}</label></p>
        <p><label>Password: {{input  value=user.password type="password" id="password" required="true"}}</label></p>

        <p><label>Confirm Password: {{input value=user.confirm type="password" id="confirm" required="true"}}</label></p>
        </br>

        <p><label>Email: {{input type="email" value=user.email required="true"}}</label></p>
        <p><label>Address: {{input type="text" value=user.address required="true"}}</label></p>
        <p><label>Age: {{input type="number" value=user.age required="true"}}</label></p>
        <button id="submit" {{bind-attr disabled="cannot_submit"}}>Submit form</button>
        <button {{action "clear"}}>Clear</button>
        <p></p>
        <button> {{#link-to 'login'}}Already member{{/link-to}}</button>
    </form>

    {{message}}
</script>
```

signup controller code.

```
App.SignupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    // User is the model used for binding the view and the controller
    // If you look at the view, you will see user.username, and user.password being
    // used as input values
    // BTW this is a JavaScript object, (i.e in JSON)

    user: {
        //These values are just place holders for the moment
        name: "",
        username: "",
        email: "",
        address: "",
        age: "",
        password: "",
        confirm: "",

    },



    // The functions called when and event is triggered from the view (i.e button click)
    actions: {
        // Action called when form is submitted, refer to form action attribute in view
        submit: function() {

            var self = this;
            var submitUser = {};

            submitUser.name = self.user.name;
            submitUser.username = self.user.username;
            submitUser.password = self.user.password;
            submitUser.cpassword = self.user.confirm;
            submitUser.email = self.user.email;
            submitUser.address = self.user.address;
            submitUser.age = self.user.age;



            // This is the API call to the web services, it uses the user (this.user) to send 
            // the login info, and recives either the logged in user info, or an error

                console.debug(this.user);
                console.debug(this.submitUser);


            $.post("http://herukoapp.com/users", JSON.stringify(this.user), function(data,status){
                data = JSON.parse(data);


                console.debug(data);
            });
        },

        // Called when the clear button is clicked, see button tag in view
        clear: function() {
            this.set('user.name', "");
            this.set('user.username', "");
            this.set('user.password', "");
            this.set('user.confirm', "");
            this.set('user.email', "");
            this.set('user.address', "");
            this.set('user.age', "");


        }
    },


});
```

Comment: i dont see anything in your SignupController that would do password matching. Did you leave that in your ApplicationController?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [computed property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) to track whether user.password and user.confirm are the same.

In Coffeescript:

```
confirmSame: (->
    password = @get('user.password')
    confirm = @get('user.confirm')

    if password == confirm
        return true
    else
        return false
).property('user.password', 'user.confirm')
```

Or in regular javascript (I think):

```
confirmSame: function() {
    password = this.get('user.password')
    confirm = this.get('user.confirm')
    if password == confirm
        return true
    else
        return false
}.property('user.password', 'user.confirm')
```

You can do a conditional with this in your template:

```
{{#if confirmSame))
    <div>Password and Confirm Password are the same</div>
{{else}}
    <div>Password and Confirm Password are not the same</div>
{{/if}}
```

And in your submit action you can check for whether confirmSame is true or false:

Coffeescript:

```
if @get('confirmSame')
    # do submit stuff
```

Or in javascript (I think):

```
if (this.get('confirmSame') == true)
    // do submit stuff
```

Comment: Where i put the
if (this.get('confirmSame') == true)
??